# Getting around similar-variable repetition in if statements

Tags: java, android, loops, reflection

I believe I'm asking a slightly different take on the perennial question of avoiding code repetition.  The setup is fairly standard--a bunch of if statements taking similar actions.  Below you'll find a short example.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to tackle situations like this, in terms of code efficiency, compactness, and programmer ease.  Note that separate solutions addressing each of those points are fine, indeed preferable, as I doubt one solution hits all three.

For example, one possible solution that came to mind seems like it would be ungainly and slow, especially on a mobile device like android, plus it would only work if the variables were instance variables, and not merely local (which may very well be the case).  The idea involved a for statement whose initialization expression would use double-brace initialization to fill a hashmap with strings corresponding to the variables involved (e.g. "installText" maps to "installPermission"), then the for-loop would contain one of the if--else-if--else-if clauses below, which would use reflection to access the variables by their names stored in the hashmap.

How can I do this better?  Thanks in advance for your time and advice!

```
if (installText.equals("Default")) {
    installPermission = DEFAULT;
} else if (installText.equals("Allow")) {
    installPermission = ENABLED;
} else if (installText.equals("Disallow")) {
    installPermission = DISABLED;
}
if (uninstallText.equals("Default")) {
    uninstallPermission = DEFAULT;
} else if (uninstallText.equals("Allow")) {
    uninstallPermission = ENABLED;
} else if (uninstallText.equals("Disallow")) {
    uninstallPermission = DISABLED;
}
if (runText.equals("Default")) {
    runPermission = DEFAULT;
} else if (runText.equals("Allow")) {
    runPermission = ENABLED;
} else if (runText.equals("Disallow")) {
    runPermission = DISABLED;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a `Map<String, State>`? It seems like all your if statements could be replaced by `fooPermission = map.get(fooText)`.

Comment: I'm actually curious why your variables are based on a string anyway. Can you explain what exactly you're doing in this instance? We might be able to suggest a better solution with more information.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Java 7? In that case you can use the `switch` statement which now supports `String` values:

```
switch(installText) {
    case "Allow":
        installPermission = ENABLED;
        break;
    case "Disallow":
        installPermission = DISABLED;
        break;
    case "Default":
        installPermission = DEFAULT;
        break;  
    default:
        installPermission = DEFAULT;
        break;  
}
```

Comment: While I do agree that the switch is great, it still leaves the code unrefactored.

Comment: But does it need to be shorter? The code is readable, understandable and easily extendable. I don't see a reason to complicate it with more data structures and what not.

Comment: Oh how nice, I wasn't aware of that addition with SE 7.  That'll definitely come in useful in some cases, and is surely preferable to the numerous "ifs", but a couple of questions remain.  Assuming that the switch is inside a for loop, there's still the issue of replacing "installText" and "installPermission" with the appropriate variables (install, uninstall, run, & so on, assuming many more).  Also, though I'm asking my question from an academic perspective, I ran into the inspiration while working on android, so no Java 7 for me here.  Definite thanks for the content of your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Extract the value checking to a separate method (I'm re-using part of Simeon Visser's answer with improvements):

```
public String getPermission(String permission)
{
    String state = null;

    // If this is Java 7:
    /*
    switch(permission)
    {
        case "Allow":
             state = ENABLED;
             break;
        case "Disallow":
             state = DISABLED;
             break;
        case "Default":
        default:
             state = DEFAULT;
             break;  
    }
    */

    // If this is Java < 7:
    if (permission.equalsIgnoreCase("allow"))
        state = ENABLED;
    else if (permission.equalsIgnoreCase("disallow"))
        state = DISABLED;
    else
        state = DEFAULT;

    return state;
}

public void callingMethod(String permission)
{
     installPermission = getPermissionState(permission);
     uninstallPermission = getPermissionState(permission);
     runPermission = getPermissionState(permission);
}
```

Furthermore, `ENABLED`, `DISABLED` and `DEFAULT` should simply be defined as constants in your class:

```
public static final String ENABLED = "ENABLED";
public static final String DISABLED = "DISABLED";
public static final String DEFAULT = "DEFAULT";
```

However, I still fail to grasp your idea with the reflection...? I don't find it necessary here, unless you have a use case whose code you're not showing at the moment...?

Comment: Ahh yes that's certainly a viable option for dealing with the multiple variables.  Takes the complexity of a data structure right out of things.  I'm still interested in those alternatives and others, since I'm positioning this question as coming from an academic point of view (though, as noted in my comment to Simeon's answer, the inspiration is from a project I'm working on in android).  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

if you are 100% sure, that the string value will be one of these three. then you can do it as follows:

```
Map<String,String> map;
map.put("Default", "Default");
map.put("Allow", "Allow");
map.put("Disallow", "Disallow");
installPermission = map.get(installText);
uninstallPermission = map.get(uninstallText);
runPermission = map.get(runText);
```

cheers